# Pacote pandas não reconhecido no jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, ciência-de-dados

Olá, alguém pode ajudar a entender pq o jupyter notebook não reconhece o pacote panda?

criei um ambiente virtual e instalei os pacotes para fazer analise de um conjunto de dados do enem, mas ao chamar o jupyter notebook e digitar: `import pandas as pd` surge a mensagem abaixo.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0efef42136cf> in <module>
----> 1 microdadosEnem = pd.read_csv("brutos/microdados_enem_2018/DADOS/MICRODADOS_ENEM_2018.csv")

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Comment: Olá Michele, você está usando o Jupyter na sua máquina local, ou atraves de algum site? E porque fazer um ambiente virtual para usa-lo? Pois, o mesmo já é meio que um ambiênte virtual isolado.

Comment: Antes de importar o pandas use `!pip install pandas` com o ponto de exclamação na frente. Depois é só rodar a célula

Comment: Olá @Elias Oliveira, eu criei um ambiente virtual e chamo o jupyter do prompt de comando ai vou para o navegador...

Comment: Olá @PauloMarques, vou fazer o que vc disse para ver se dá certo...

Comment: Entendi, nesse caso é só fazer como o @PauloMarques falou e usar o !pip install pandas

Comment: O erro é `NameError: name 'pd' is not defined`, e não `ImportError: No module named pandas`. Ou seja, vc não rodou o comando `import pandas as pd` e tentou utilizar o `pd`. O Paulo já fez um comentário disso na "resposta" da Michele (que não é uma resposta e deveria ser um comentário), mas só estou ressaltando.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que deveria realizar o seguinte comando no seu terminal.

```
pip install pandas
```

Lembrando que depois de realizar esse procedimento do pip, você deverá colocar no inicio do seu código:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Aí sim o modulo pandas será executado com sucesso!

**Deve-se lembrar que se você estiver tentando fazer isso localmente é recomendável que se instale a variavel de ambiente. Segue um link de como realizar esse procedimento:**

https://medium.com/@victorromariopazdejesus/python-3-configurando-vari%C3%A1veis-de-ambiente-no-windows-10-63059c7192e6